# C++ ternary operator string concatenation

Tags: c++

I have seen this question asked for other languages, but not C++. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
bool a = true;
string s;
s.append("a:" + (a? "true" : "false"));    
cout << s << endl;
```

I get a compiler error stating that I cannot add two pointers. What gives?

Comment: String literals are `const char[N]`s.

Comment: `const char *` + `const char *` <- this. String literals are effectively pointers.

Comment: To be clear - `"a:"` is indeed `const char[3]`, but arrays automatically treated as pointers on arithmetic operations

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
s.append(string("a:") + (a? "true" : "false"));
```

Answer (score 5):

`"true"`, `"false"`, `"a:"`, `"b:"` and `"c:"` are pointers (raw char arrays, actually). When you add them together with `+` (e.g. `"a:" + "true"`) , then `std::string` is not involved, and it's only `std::string` which actually gives `+` the meaning of concatenation.

Here's what I do in such situations:

```
s += "a:" + std::string(a ? "true" : "false");
```

Answer (score 3):

Just noting this, but when C++14 comes around, this will become even easier. Firstly, this can currently be written using `operator+=` instead of `append`:

```
s += std::string("a:") + (a ? "true" : "false");
```

In C++14, there will be a standard `operator""s`, which means this is possible:

```
s += "a:"s + (a ? "true" : "false");
```

However, the one that still makes the most sense to use in both cases, based on the shown code, is [DigitalEye's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22412011/962089), since it removes the need for a cast altogether. I imagine your real code is different, though, which means this could soon be useful (or already, given a C++14 standard library implementation being in use).

Comment: Interesting note about C++14. Also, is there any advantage to using `operator+=` over `append` other than readability?

Comment: @Gareth, I personally think it's more natural. `append` can do things like append a range, though, so `operator+=` isn't sufficient. I don't know of anything `operator+=` can do extra off hand.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 bool a;

 string s;
 s.append(string("a:") + (a? "true" : "false"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you try to concatenate two strings which are arrays of type `char`. `"a:"` is of type `const char[3]` and you cannot concatenate such strings with `+` operator. You have to use type `string`  which has defined `+` operator which can be used to concatenate strings:

```
s.append(std::string("a:") + (a? "true" : "false"));
```

Answer (score 1):

"a:" is char const[3] and (a? "true" : "false") is also char const[5] (for true) or char const[6] (for false), so you are applying + operator to two pointers.

The code below will work, because you are calling the overloaded += of string class that takes char const* as parameter:

```
s = "a:"
s +=  a ? "true": "false";
```

Comment: They are not `const char *`, but `const char[3]`, and `const char[5]` or `const char[6]` respectively. By the time they're added, however, they are both `const char *`s for the operation.